# F# overly aggressive type inference?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, type-inference

So in doing some of the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems, I want to be able to take the square root of integer values (int, long, bigint, etc), but Sqrt is only defined for floating-point values.  So I've been writing my own little Newton-Raphson algorithm, and it's plenty accurate for what I need.  However, I want to be able to call the built-in sqrt function on floating-point values.  So I wrote something like this:

```
let inline dsqrt x =
    match box x with
    | :? float -> sqrt x
    | :? float32 -> sqrt x
    | _ -> p_dsqrt x
```

My function, obviously, is named "p_dsqrt".  However, this function requires that the input have a Sqrt method defined, which sort of defeats the whole purpose.  Am I missing some type constraint, or what?

Comment: In case it's of use, here's the code I use for integral square roots in my Euler problems: http://fssnip.net/dR

Comment: And what is the intended return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want this, instead:

```
let dsqrt x =
    match box x with
    | :? float as f -> sqrt f |> box :?> 'a
    | :? float32 as f -> sqrt f |> box :?> 'a
    | _ -> p_dsqrt x
```

The problem with your code is that you're directly calling `sqrt x`, which constrains the possible types of `x`.  In my modified code I bind a new identifier to the result of the successful coercion to `float` or `float32`, so this doesn't put any constraint on the type of `x`.

Comment: Shouldn't `dsqrt` still be `inline`, though, to correctly propagate `x`'s type to `p_dsqrt`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm just getting a different error now.  I get "The type 'float' does not match the type 'float32'".  When I remove the 'float32' case, the function still resolves to "float -> float".  For reference, my p_dsqrt function resolves to "'a -> 'a".

Comment: @LeeCrabtree - sorry, I updated my answer.  There needs to be a dynamic conversion back to the generic type, too.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the match, the inline keyword is not required but if you want to use an inline function and "hat types", use overloading instead of match:

```
type Sqrt = Sqrt with
    // Dummy overload in order to get the right types inferred (will never reach here)
    static member inline ($) (Sqrt, _:^t when ^t:null and ^t: struct) = id

    // Existing sqrt
    static member inline ($) (Sqrt, x:'a) :'a = sqrt x 

    // Your Newton-Raphson based sqrt's
    static member        ($) (Sqrt, x:int   ) = sqrtForInt    x
    static member        ($) (Sqrt, x:bigint) = sqrtForBigInt x 

let inline sqrt (x:'t) :'t = Sqrt $ x
```

The return type will always be the same as the input type and the implementation of sqrt chosen will depend on that type. This selection will happen at compile-time which is the main difference with the match method which is resolved at run-time.

If I take out the dummy overload, it will have the same problem as your code: it will require the sqrt constraint.

Comment: Wow this is just brilliant :)

Comment: How does this work? I can't make sense of what I'm reading! The result is impressive though.